# flask: request.json always returns none despite of sending valid json

Tags: python, json, rest, api, flask

i have this code on server side

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/pingtest")
def pingtest():
    return "Pong!"

@app.route("/registrar_alumno", methods=["POST"])
def registrar_alumno():
    print(request.json)
    return jsonify(request.json)

app.run(debug=True,port=4000)
```

and on the client i have this code

```
import requests

r=requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:4000/registrar_alumno",
    data={"test":"hello there"})
print(r.text)
```

i expect to obtain {"test":"hello there"} in both sides but i have this on server:

> (asistencias) PS
> C:\Users\Alumno\Desktop\Proyectos\py\gestion_academica\asistencias>
> python .\server.py
> [...] (irrelevants messages that server always shows)
>
> None #...(this should be print(request.json) instruction)
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2020 16:22:45] "←[37mPOST /registrar_alumno HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -

and this on client

> (asistencias) PS
> C:\Users\Alumno\Desktop\Proyectos\py\gestion_academica\asistencias>
> python .\testclient.py
>
> None

i have no idea what's wrong with this, i hope someone can help me to found the bug

Comment: sorry in the client below a obtain "null" instead of None

Comment: i tried on client requests.post function: headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"} 
but now i have an error:<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>

Comment: The formatting on this makes it kind of hard to read. Can you post more of the response from client and server and format with ```?. Also, your POST request did generate a 200 (successful response)?

Comment: @JosefacundoBogado, you cannot just pass the header, the data needs to be encoded properly. Use the `json` parameter instead of `data`.

Comment: thanks, i know this is a foolish question but for some reason i dont notice this when a have read the requests´s docs

Comment: i supossed that if i want to use data instead of json ¿i should use request.form attribute in server side?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the `data` parameter with a dictionary in your client request which sends form-encoded data, causing `request.json` to return `None`.

Use the `json` parameter to send JSON:

```py
import requests

r=requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:4000/registrar_alumno", json={"test":"hello there"})
```

This will serialize the data as JSON and change the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

See the requests docs on [more complicated POST requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: hi, thats great, i found another solution, not so good idea, i put data=json.dumps({dict}) and it works too, but your answer is clearly the most properly